# Как получить уникальный идентификатор процессора (CPU) средствами C++?

Tags: c++, процессор

Интересуют методы через которые можно получить id процессора средствами c++.

Comment: Что такое «id процессора»?

Comment: средствами c++ - никак, используйте интринсики или соотв. библиотеки

Comment: @Эникейщик уникальный индификатор процессор.

Comment: Был бы рад любым референсам.

Comment: уникальный идентификатор получить так не получится https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX=3:_Processor_Serial_Number

Comment: А платформа какая? Тип, архитектура проца и операционная система? cat /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: @eri Ось - windows. Архитектуры могут быть разные.

Comment: В компе м.б. более одного процессора (обычно для серверов). Конечно, вы не рассказали о всей задаче, но возможно  для идентификации всей системы стоит взять MAC-адрес первичного сетевого интерфейса.

Comment: @avp Задача состоит в получение данных от клиента для бана. Нужны любые уникальные данные о компьютере которые записываются в бд. Из наших наблюдений у людей с взломанной виндой совпадают айди матери и cpu. По этому ищем другие пути. Мак адрес должен быть уникален, но у некоторых юзеров встречаются ошибки с ACCESS_VIOLATION.

Comment: попробуйте через`asm { mov eax,N \n CPUID }`. И сделайте себе класс, если вам это так нравится. https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_45.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не каждый процессор возвращает в CPUID уникальный серийный номер. Чтобы уникально идентифицировать компьютер, имеет смысл использовать составной аппаратный идентификатор, состоящий из нескольких значений, например:

- CPUID
- SMBIOS System UUID
- Серийный номер системника
- Серийный номер материнской платы

Все эти значения можно программно получить из [таблицы SMBIOS](https://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios). MAC-адреса сетевых интерфейсов, конечно, тоже можно добавить, но следует помнить, что компьютер может иметь несколько сетевых интерфейсов, нельзя просто взять первый попавшийся - он может быть виртуальным.

Пример для Windows (код для чтения таблицы SMBIOS взят из проекта [sysinv](https://github.com/cavaliercoder/sysinv/blob/master/smbios.cpp)):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// SMBIOS Table Type numbers
#define SMB_TABLE_BIOS              0
#define SMB_TABLE_SYSTEM            1
#define SMB_TABLE_BASEBOARD         2
#define SMB_TABLE_CHASSIS           3
#define SMB_TABLE_PROCESSOR         4
#define SMB_TABLE_MEMCTRL           5
#define SMB_TABLE_MEMMODULES        6
#define SMB_TABLE_PORTS             8
#define SMB_TABLE_SLOTS             9
#define SMB_TABLE_OEM_STRINGS       11
#define SMB_TABLE_SYS_CFG_OPTIONS   12
#define SMB_TABLE_MEM_ARRAY         16
#define SMB_TABLE_MEM_DEVICE        17
#define SMB_TABLE_END_OF_TABLE      127

// 64bit Word type
typedef unsigned long long QWORD;

/*
* Structures
*/
typedef struct _RawSmbiosData
{
    BYTE    Used20CallingMethod;
    BYTE    SMBIOSMajorVersion;
    BYTE    SMBIOSMinorVersion;
    BYTE    DmiRevision;
    DWORD   Length;
    BYTE    SMBIOSTableData[1];
} RAW_SMBIOS_DATA, * PRAW_SMBIOS_DATA;

typedef struct _SmbiosStructHeader
{
    BYTE Type;
    BYTE Length;
    WORD Handle;
} SMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER, *PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER;

// Structures
typedef struct _NODE {
    wchar_t *Name;                      // Name of the node
    struct _NODE_ATT_LINK *Attributes;  // Array of attributes linked to the node
    struct _NODE *Parent;               // Parent node
    struct _NODE_LINK *Children;        // Array of linked child nodes
    int Flags;                          // Node configuration flags
} NODE, * PNODE;

typedef struct _NODE_LINK {
    struct _NODE *LinkedNode;           // Node attached to this node
} NODE_LINK, * PNODE_LINK;

typedef struct _NODE_ATT {
    wchar_t *Key;                       // Attribute name
    wchar_t *Value;                     // Attribute value string (may be null separated multistring if NAFLG_ARRAY is set)
    int Flags;                          // Attribute configuration flags
} NODE_ATT, *PNODE_ATT;

typedef struct _NODE_ATT_LINK {
    struct _NODE_ATT *LinkedAttribute;  // Attribute linked to this node
} NODE_ATT_LINK, *PNODE_ATT_LINK;


/********************************************************************/

PRAW_SMBIOS_DATA GetSmbiosData()
{
    DWORD bufferSize = 0;

    PRAW_SMBIOS_DATA smbios = NULL;

    // Get required buffer size
    bufferSize = GetSystemFirmwareTable('RSMB', 0, NULL, 0);
    if (bufferSize) {
        smbios = (PRAW_SMBIOS_DATA)LocalAlloc(LPTR, bufferSize);
        bufferSize = GetSystemFirmwareTable('RSMB', 0, (PVOID)smbios, bufferSize);
    }

    return smbios;
}

PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER GetNextStructure(PRAW_SMBIOS_DATA smbios,PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER previous)
{
    PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER next = NULL;
    PBYTE c = NULL;
    
    // Return NULL is no data found
    if (NULL == smbios)
        return NULL;

    // Return first table if previous was NULL
    if (NULL == previous)
        return (PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER)(&smbios->SMBIOSTableData[0]);

    // Move to the end of the formatted structure
    c = ((PBYTE)previous) + previous->Length;

    // Search for the end of the unformatted structure (\0\0)
    while (true) {
        if ('\0' == *c && '\0' == *(c + 1)) {
            /* Make sure next table is not beyond end of SMBIOS data
             * (Thankyou Microsoft for ommitting the structure count
             * in GetSystemFirmwareTable
             */
            if ((c + 2) < ((PBYTE)smbios->SMBIOSTableData + smbios->Length))
                return (PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER)(c + 2);
            else
                return NULL; // We reached the end
        }

        c++;
    }

    return NULL;
}

PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER GetNextStructureOfType(PRAW_SMBIOS_DATA smbios,PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER previous, DWORD type)
{
    PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER next = previous;
    while (NULL != (next = GetNextStructure(smbios,next))) {
        if (type == next->Type)
            return next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER GetStructureByHandle(PRAW_SMBIOS_DATA smbios,WORD handle)
{
    PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER header = NULL;

    while (NULL != (header = GetNextStructure(smbios,header)))
        if (handle == header->Handle)
            return header;

    return NULL;
}

void GetSmbiosString(PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER table, BYTE index, LPWSTR output, int cchOutput)
{
    DWORD i = 0;
    DWORD len = 0;
    wcscpy(output,L"");

    if (0 == index) return;

    char *c = NULL;

    for (i = 1, c = (char *)table + table->Length; '\0' != *c; c += strlen(c) + 1, i++) {
        if (i == index) {
            len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, c, -1, output,cchOutput);
            break;
        }
    }
}

//вывод значения числового параметра таблицы SMBIOS по указанному смещению
void PrintBiosValue(PRAW_SMBIOS_DATA smbios,DWORD type,DWORD offset, DWORD size)
{
    PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER head=NULL;
    PBYTE cursor = NULL; 

    head = GetNextStructureOfType(smbios,head, type);
    if (NULL == head){ printf("PrintBiosValue Error!\n");return;}

    cursor=((PBYTE)head+offset);

    //value           
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        printf("%02x",(unsigned int) *cursor);     
        cursor++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//вывод значения строкового параметра таблицы SMBIOS по указанному смещению
void PrintBiosString(PRAW_SMBIOS_DATA smbios,DWORD type,DWORD offset)
{
    PSMBIOS_STRUCT_HEADER head;
    head=NULL;
    PBYTE cursor = NULL;
    WCHAR buf[1024];

    head = GetNextStructureOfType(smbios,head, type);
    if (NULL == head){printf("PrintString Error!\n");return;}
    cursor=((PBYTE)head+offset);
    BYTE val=*cursor;
        
    GetSmbiosString((head), *cursor,buf,1024);
    //  value           
    wprintf(L"%s\n",buf);
}

int main(){

    PRAW_SMBIOS_DATA data = GetSmbiosData();

    if(data==NULL){
        printf("Can't get SMBIOS data!"); 
        return 1;
    }

    printf("System UUID: ");
    PrintBiosValue(data,SMB_TABLE_SYSTEM,8, 16);

    printf("Chassis serial: ");
    PrintBiosString(data,SMB_TABLE_CHASSIS,7);

    printf("Motherboard serial: ");
    PrintBiosString(data,SMB_TABLE_BASEBOARD,7);

    printf("CPUID: ");
    PrintBiosValue(data,SMB_TABLE_PROCESSOR,8, 8);  //Таблица SMBIOS содержит только 2 DWORD-значения CPUID из 4, но этого обычно достаточно

    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте через команду **cpuid**. Полная инструкция :

https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_45.html

Может быть там есть, что вы ищете. Пример :

```
# include <cstdint>
# include <cstdio>
struct CPUIDinfo
    {
        uint32_t EAX;
        uint32_t EBX;
        uint32_t ECX;
        uint32_t EDX;
    };

    static inline void CpuId(unsigned int func, unsigned int subfunc,
CPUIDinfo& info)
    {
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "cpuid"
            : "=a"(info.EAX), "=b"(info.EBX), "=c"(info.ECX), "=d"(info.EDX)
            : "a"(func), "c"(subfunc)
        );
    }

int main(){
for(int i=0;i<6;++i){
  CPUIDinfo info;
  CpuId(i,0,info);
  printf("%d,0:%d,%d,%d,%d\n",i,info.EAX,info.EBX,info.ECX,info.EDX);}
}
```

> 4.2. Forming the 96-bit Processor Serial Number The 96-bit processor serial number is the concatenation of three 32-bit entities. To access
>   the most significant 32-bits of the processor serial number the
>   program should set the EAX register parameter value to “1” and then
>   execute the CPUID instruction as follows: MOV EAX, 01H CPUID After
>   execution of the CPUID instruction, the EAX register contains the
>   Processor Signature. The Processor Signature comprises the most
>   significant 32-bits of the processor serial number. The value in EAX
>   should be saved prior to gathering the remaining 64-bits of the
>   processor serial number. To access the remaining 64-bits of the
>   processor serial number the program should set the EAX register
>   parameter value to “3” and then execute the CPUID instruction as
>   follows: MOV EAX, 03H CPUID After execution of the CPUID instruction,
>   the EDX register contains the middle 32-bits, and the ECX register
>   contains the least significant 32-bits of the processor serial number.
>   Software may then concatenate the saved Processor Signature, EDX, and
>   ECX before returning the complete 96-bit processor serial number.
>   Processor serial number should be displayed as 6 groups of 4 hex
>   nibbles (Ex. XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX where X represents a hex
>   digit). Alpha hex characters should be displayed as capital letters.

Судя по приватности запрос с `EAX=0x03` всегда возвращает ноль. Пользуйтесь всей другой доступной информацией. Иногда люди пользуются виртуальными компьютерами. Так-что запрос идентичности не очень получиться у вас.

Comment: нет, там этого нет, см. ссылку в моем комментарии к вопросу. Ну и, конечно, не стоит использовать `__asm__ __volatile__`