# Получение уникального идентификатора компьютера на Windows

Tags: c++, windows, идентификация

[тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1173117/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) уже задавал вопрос и таки не дубликат.
т.е. я использовал решение оттуда и оно не подходит вообще:
у меня показывает такие данные

[image: мои данные]

а на втором компьютере
[image: другие данные]

при этом начало "Motherboard serial:" при каждом запуске разное
в итоге нечего из представленного не уникальное и не стабильно

Comment: Никто и не обещал, что все параметры будут уникальными, в противном случае и не требовалось бы делать составной идентификатор. На втором компьютере сразу видно, что материнка полная лажа - производитель заложил в серийный номера чушь типа ffff, 1234 - тут медицина бессильна. А по поводу "яЮя" в начале, это видимо баг в моем коде, но у себя я его воспроизвести не могу - у меня такого не наблюдается (честно выводится "To be filled by OEM"). Покажите вывод команды `wmic bios get /value`, подумаю в чем может быть дело.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight вот https://pastebin.com/Acj2hanJ

Comment: + если предложенный дубликат не помог, не нужно было соглашаться с закрытием, и все тут. Я бы отозвал голос, плодить вопросы не обязательно.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight за закрытие конечно извиняюсь поспешил, если бы можно было открыть обратно то я бы так и сделал вместо создания нового ..

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight  а тут https://pastebin.com/YuycNKWJ данные со второго компьютера

Comment: Попробуйте обновленный вариант кода: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1015604/240512